# Phpmailer not in Hotmail Inbox or Spam?

Tags: php, phpmailer

So i thought that if you send email to hotmail it would at least arrive in spam but in this case it does not. So have i done something wrong in this code below? I tested the same code with Gmail and it works Perfectly. Sure i think its related to Hotmail Filters.

Things to note, I have setup the email address on my domain and i have an SPF Record setup.

What could be wrong? And how can i check it?

Current PHP:

```
<?php 

    require 'PHPmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = true;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "smtpout.secureserver.net"; // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port
    $mail->Username   = "username"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "password";        // SMTP account password
    $mail->setFrom('email', 'Immortal Insurance');
    $mail->AddAddress('sendtoemail');
    $mail->AddAddress('sendtoemail');
    $mail->Body       = 'This is a test Email';
    $mail->AddAttachment('tosend/policy.pdf');
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: Usually there is something that can help you out in your mail log: /var/log/maillog

Comment: @HansWassink This is a Windows Hosting is it any different for where the maillog would be?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. A quick google search lead me here though: http://www.winservermart.com/HowTo/SMTP_Logs.aspx

Comment: @Synchro I found finally the emails came through to Spam, It says Smart Filter has classified the email as spam. Is there any method to improve the email code?

Comment: The code is fine, but you need to ensure that the rest of your email system is good - make sure that your mail server has matching forward and reverse DNS, that you have appropriate SPF records set up, ideally DKIM and DMARC too. There's no magic solution for not being classified as spam - otherwise the spammers would use it - you just need to be on your best behaviour and establish a good sending reputation.

Comment: @Synchro Can you provide me relevant resource to help is getting these setup. Its a windows host, and i have setup the spf(not sure if correct), and the email is real as i added it to the domain. I am unsure what DKIM or DMARC is and how to implement it using Windows Hosting. Also When you say reputation does that mean that if the emails keep sending eventually they will appear in the inbox? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Check your SPF at [Scott Kitterman's site](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html). [DKIM](http://www.dkim.org) is a bit more involved, but is especially needed for yahoo addresses. DMARC is a kind of layer on top of SPF and DKIM - check out [dmarcian.com](http://dmarcian.com) for help on that. Yes, the way reputation works these days is that if you consistently send email that the recipients do not mark as spam, and that the recipients actually read (as monitored by all webmail services), and you handle bounces correctly, you won't be put in the spam folder.

Comment: @Synchro SPF record passed validation test with pySPF (Python SPF library)! that should mean that he email should work using phpmailer right? spf: v=spf1 ip4:182.50.130.73 -all, DKIM is some kind of rsa key, do i need to specify DKIM when using phpmailer?

Comment: That's a very tight SPF record, a good thing! Yes, DKIM requires you create a key pair - put the public key in DNS, provide PHPMailer with the paths to private and public keys and a selector to sign with. There's a simple [DKIM signing example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/test/phpmailerTest.php#L1660) in the unit tests.

Comment: @Synchro Can you please write an answer how each of these SPF/DKIM/DMARC should be formatted. Also i am unsure if the spf is correct. It should work with immortalinsurance.com. Thanks.

Comment: Each of those requires many pages to describe, not really what SO is for. There are plenty of tutorials and examples on all of these, just search for them. I can't tell you whether your SPF is correct (though it's likely you want an 'mx' clause in it) - it's certainly syntactically correct, but I don't know about your entire email infrastructure.

Comment: Okay thanks @Synchro, i will work on these and see if it gets fixed, otherwise i will just presume it will be related to domain reputation. Thanks for your info :)

Comment: @Synchro Last thing, how come Web Mail works but phpmailer does not? With the current setup i have no DKIM or DMARC(unsure).

Comment: Is your web mail sending from the same server as PHPMailer? It might be interesting to compare the headers on messages from each source, see what the differences are.

Comment: Well i know that webmail is coming from secureserver.net and well my smtp is setup with that server so i hope thats right.